# Create x amount of thread, and then wait for then to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a console application to read json files and then do some processing with them. I have 200k json files to process, so I'm creating a thread per file. But I would like to have only 30 active threads running. I don't know how to control it in Java.

This is the piece of code I have so far:

```
 for (String jsonFile : result) {
 
    final String jsonFilePath = jsonFile;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        String filePath = jsonFilePath;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    });
    thread.start(); 
}
```

`result` is an array with the path of 200k files. From this point, I'm not sure how to control it. I thought about a `List<Thread>` and then in each thread implements a notifier and when they finish just remove from the list. But then I would have to make the main thread sleep and then wake-up. Which feels weird.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "*...so I'm creating a thread per file*" - Don't. Use an `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: @Turing85 figuring out how to do that

Comment: From what you describe a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) seems fitting

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651427/how-to-make-a-thread-limit-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to not create one thread per file. Threads are limited resources. Creating too many can lead to starvation or even program abortion.

From what information was provided, I would use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Constructing such an Executor with a limited amount of threads is quite simple thanks to [`Executors::newFixedSizeThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)):

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedSizeThreadPool(30);
```

Looking at the [`ExecutorService`-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), method [`<T> Future<T> submit​(Callable<T> task)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) might be fitting.

For this, some changes will be necessary. The tasks (i.e. what is currently a `Runnable` in the given implementation) must be converted to a [`Callable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), where `T` should be substituted with the return-type. The [`Future<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) returned should then be collected into a list and waited upon on. When all `Future`s have completed, the result list can be constructed, e.g. through streaming.

Comment: Thanks! I'm implementing this. I'll rate the answer as I finish

Comment: Just to compliment the answer. See this link https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/

Answer (score 0):

With `parallelStreams` and `ForkJoinPool` maybe you can get a more straightforward code, plus, an easy way to collect the results of your files after processing. For parallel processing, I prefer to directly use Threads, as a last resort, only when `parallelStream` can't be used.

```
boolean doStuff( String file){
  // do your magic here
  System.out.println( "The file " + file + " has been processed." );
  // return the status of the processed file
  return true; 
}

List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

jsonFiles.add("file1");
jsonFiles.add("file2");
jsonFiles.add("file3");
...
jsonFiles.add("file200000");

ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = null;

try {
  final int parallelism = 30;
  forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
  forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
        jsonFiles.parallelStream()
        .map( jsonFile -> doStuff( jsonFile) )
        .collect(Collectors.toList())  // you can collect this to a List<Boolea> results
      ).get(); 
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (forkJoinPool != null) {
    forkJoinPool.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your jobs (filenames) into a queue, start 30 threads to process them, then wait until all threads are done. For example:

```
    static ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String> jobQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String>();

    private static class Worker implements Runnable {

        int threadNumber;

        public Worker(int threadNumber) {
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadNumber + " started");

                while (true) {
                    // get the next filename from job queue
                    String fileName;
                    try {
                        fileName = jobQueue.pop();
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                        // The queue is empty, exit the loop
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Thread " + threadNumber + " processing file " + fileName);
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // so something useful here
                    System.out.println("Thread " + threadNumber + " finished file " + fileName);
                }

                System.out.println("Thread " + threadNumber + " finished");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Create dummy filenames for testing:
        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
            jobQueue.push("Testfile" + i + ".json");
        }

        System.out.println("Starting threads");

        // Create 30 worker threads
        List<Thread> workerThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker(i));
            workerThreads.add(thread);
            thread.start();
        }

        // Wait until the threads are all finished
        for (Thread thread : workerThreads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```